# Error while embedding Python in a C++ application: undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'

Tags: c++, python-3.x, dev-c++

```
#define PY_SSIZE_T_CLEAN
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>



int main()
{
    char filename[] = "quickstart.py";
    FILE* fp;

    Py_Initialize();

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    PyRun_SimpleFile(fp, filename);

    Py_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

I wanted to embed a python script into my c++ application and I also added the path to Python\Python310\include and Python\Python310\Lib to Dev-c++ but still, I am getting this error

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Initialize'
main.cpp:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `_imp__PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags'
main.cpp:(.text+0x7d): undefined reference to `_imp__Py_Finalize'
[Error] ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor and switch to a more recent IDE than Dev-C++, it hasn't been really updated for two decades. I recommend Qt Creator which will be much more helpful, and supports modern build systems.

Comment: Somewhere there is a library containing the missing symbols that you need to add to your build.

Comment: Oh, Thank you! I will try Qt Creator.